# Quantitatively compare FFTs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I have multiple FFTs as seen in the pic.
The blue trace is my control trace (my gold standard).
I want to quantitatively compare the coherence between the other traces and the blue trace.

I am aware of mscohere (magnitude squared coherence), but this function computes the power spectrum estimates using Welchs method and then compares the resulting spectrums.

I want to compare the exact FFT data seen below.

The FFT data is 251 samples in length with 250 fs.

Is there a method to compare the coherence of the FFT data as I have it?

[image]

Comment: `mscohere()`        Try this example `openExample('signal/MultipleCoherenceAndOrdinaryCoherenceExample')`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brendan. However, that example still takes x and y as time domain signals. I am looking for a method to compute the coherence on the FFTs I already have.

Comment: Coherence is a normalization of cross-spectral densities . Cross-spectral densities are an integral of signal correlation over time. It is not possible to determine coherence without the original time domain of your signal.